# get font face name batch file

Tags: batch-file, fonts

I'm using the script below to install fonts in Windows, but I wonder if there is how to get the name of the font face. for example the name of the source file is BebasNeue.otf, but the name of her face is Bebas Neue (OpenType), anyone knows a way to get the name of a script to register the face properly?

The script is recording the name of the source BebasNeue on record and would like him to record the name of the panel in case Bebas Neue (OpenType)

```
    @setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    @echo off

    echo instalando fontes....

    for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b \\mulinfsv0005\Configs\fonts\') do (
        set variable=%%f
        set variable=!variable:~0,-4!
        echo !variable!
        xcopy \\servidorOrigem\Configs\fonts\%%f c:\Windows\Fonts /y /q
        reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" /v !variable! /t REG_SZ /d %%f /f
    ) 
    endlocal

    echo As fontes foram instaladas!

    pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tested this with a few fonts.Not sure it will work for all possible metadata formats:

```
@echo off

setlocal
set "font_file=BebasNeue.otf"

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%# in ( 'type "%font_file%" ^| find /i "version" 2^>nul' ) do (
    set "font_face=%%#"
    goto :break_for
)
:break_for

echo %font_face%

endlocal
```

Comment: This method does not work in .ttf .fon nor .fnt fonts... `:(`

Answer (score 0):

i found this script via google.

i hope it is allowed to link another page...

http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/28817-installing-fonts-via-command-line-script.html#post1749562

maybe this helps?

Kind Regards

Comment: It would have been more convenient to take the code you refer to and put it here explicitly, adding a link as reference to the original source. By the way, the code does not solve the asker's problem since it calculates the result based on the font file name and a special suffix.

Comment: @Twonky sure, you're right. I only tried to help. As i were new to stackoverflow back in the days (the post, we're talking about is from 2014), one maybe forgive my ignorance. :)